# loop async calls in for loop and console the data after for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

`data` is coming as a blank Array `[]` whereas I was expecting data to be like an Array of object. If I tried `setTimeout(() => {console.log(data)}, 1000)` then it is console the data properly, but I don't want to use `setTimeout()` to console data in synchronous manner.

```js
let data = []; 

for(let i=1; i<11; i++) {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/` + i;
  
  (async () => {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let resJson = await response.json();
    data.push(resJson);
  })();
}

console.log(data);

/*
 * Working but don't want to use this 
setTimeout(() => {console.log(data)}, 1000);
*/
```

Comment: doesn't the function `(async () => {})();` need to be awaited too? this is the classic, once in async-land you must stay in async-land

Comment: maybe put it inside another funcion and call it right after `datapush(resJson)`

Comment: What is the point of the `(async () => {…})()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `console.log(data)` part of the code is not going to wait for the `async` block to be resolved and instead will be executed synchronously. Instead you could first push requests to one array and then resolve them with `Promise.all` and do all of that inside of IIFE.

```js
(async() => {
  let requests = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    requests.push(fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`));
  }

  const responses = await Promise.all(requests)
  const data = await Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
  console.log(data)
})();
```

Comment: I'd recommend to put the entire script inside the IIFE though